# Google App script functions are taking unusual time to be executed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, runtime, execution

I've been using google sheet and app script for almost a year now.

However today i've faced a really weird issue. Any function that i run no matter how complex or basic it is the function would take a-lot of time to be executed and most of them end with an error (exceeding execution time).

My file isn't that big it has around 5k rows with some data manipulation (14MB file when i download the entire thing)

For example when i run hideall function which hide all sheets except the "Main_Page"  it usually takes 13-15 second. However, today it kept running for 360 second and timed out afterwards.

```
function hideall () 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for(var i =0;i<ss.length;i++)
    {
      if(ss[i].getName()!= "Main_Page")
      {
        ss[i].hideSheet();
      }
    }
}
```

Taking 360 sec to run this code

[image]

What is the issue? what am i doing wrong? How can i solve it?

it's like this for any function that i run.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this happening with new scripts too? If you create a copy of the sheet and the script do you have the same issue?

Comment: @GiselleValladares  I just tried the following function  :  function trynewstuff() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('red');
  sheet.getRange('B1').setBackground('green');

}
it took around 45 seconds to execute, when i try the same function on a new file it would be executed instantly.

Comment: In that case it might be a bug, cache and cookies or a transitional issue? You can try to free cache & cookies in the browser, try a different browser or device. If all that fails, you can create an issue tracker while following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback)

Comment: In your situation, for example, when you copy your Spreadsheet and run your script in the copied Spreadsheet, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike When i do that it works as intended, so basically i've been exporting the sheets and the scripts into a new spreadsheet to solve this issue. I know it's weird since i didn't add anything new to the spreadsheet or the script.

Comment: As a side note, and I don't know if it's relevant or not but the only difference that i did to my usual routine is that i've been logging in using google authentication app instead of the password.

Comment: Question, then when you are making the copy, are  logging in using ` Google Authentication App ` or are you using the `Password`?

Comment: Google Authentication App @GiselleValladares